# AEM Developer exam with regular expressions is well performed?

Tags: aem

I'm studying for the AEM developer exam and i have a question about one of the questions: Which template allowed Paths expression would allow a page to be created with the path `/content/main/page1/page2`?

And the options are:

```
A. /content/main/?
B. /content/main/[^/]+(/,*)?
C. /content/main/[A/]+[A/]
D. /content/main/*
```

I don't understand if the question is wrong or the options are because if i choose which option validates the path (ONE OPTION) i cannot because the A, B and D are valid answers. But if i add a NOT on the question like "... would NOT allow a page to be created..." then in that case i can answer a single option like the question demands that would be the C option.

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the right answer there is `B. /content/main/[^/]+(/,*)?`.

- `/content/main/?` and `/content/main/*` are not correct because in these cases allowed paths are:

  - `/content/main`
  - `/content/main/`
- `/content/main/[A/]+[A/]` you already identified as wrong, and I agree there.

This `/content/main/[^/]+(/,*)?` regex matches path `/content/main/page1` just perfectly because it says that path should start with **/content/main/** then there should be some **non empty name**.

Remember, that property **allowedPaths** used to validate path of the page, where you are going to create new one (in this case with name **page2**).